# Why pycharm can not find this attributes and methods reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Why pycharm can not find this attributes and methods reference?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Q4H.png)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__")

        self.method_need_B()
        self.method_need_C()

        print(self.attr_need_B)
        print(self.attr_need_C)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")
        self.attr_need_B = "I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B"
        A.__init__(self)

    def method_need_B(self):
        print("I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")
        self.attr_need_C = "I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in C"
        B.__init__(self)

    def method_need_C(self):
        print("I am 'method' and A need me, but live in C")

c = C()
```

this code on picture, i am not undestand why pycharm not visible this attrs and methods
outputs without errors:

```
C.__init__
B.__init__
A.__init__
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in C
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in C
```

Comment: but this good work and output without errors:

"C.__init__
B.__init__
A.__init__
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in C
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in C"

Answer (score 1):

The script works without errors but it is very situational: it only works for the case displayed on your question.

What if, for instance, you call `c = B()`?

That's the output:

```
B.__init__
A.__init__
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    c = B()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.py", line 15, in __init__
    A.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.method_need_C()
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'method_need_C'. Did you mean: 'method_need_B'?
```

Why it didn't worked on `c = B()`, but it worked on `c = C()`?

When you assign `c` an instance of `class C`, the class constructor calls `B.__init__(self)`, which inside B constructor, it calls `A.__init__(self)`.

So, `c` is an object with A, B and C methods and properties. As all of them have different function and variable names, they do not get overwritten once you inherit each parent's data.

Now, why does `c = B()` does not work?

It's because that on `class A`, you're trying to access `class C` methods and properties, and `class C` was never initialized inside `class B` instance. So basically, as `C.__init__(self)` is never called on this instance, then `self.method_need_C()` and `self.attr_need_C` are not allocated.

Now, you asked, why on `c = C()` these methods are visible? It's because that on python, `self` refers to the instance of the class that you created, which in this case is `C`.

Sure, the script being executed is inside `class A`, but have you tried to print `self` to see what is its type inside `class A`'s constructor?

```
# By modifying your script, we now print self to see its type:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__: ", self)

        self.method_need_B()
        self.method_need_C()

        print(self.attr_need_B)
        print(self.attr_need_C)
```

This is the output:

```
C.__init__
B.__init__
A.__init__:  <__main__.C object at 0x0000029641A27B80>
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in C
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in C
```

As self refers to a `class C` instance, even inside `class A` it contains `class B` and `class C` methods and properties. So they are visible as long as you use `self` on the script.

Again, this only works because you're creating a `class C` instance. Instantiating another class type will get you lots of errors.

One thing you can do, if you really need to call `class C` and `class B` methods inside `class A`, is to use `isinstance()` function, as displayed below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__: ", self)

        if (isinstance(self, B)):
            self.method_need_B()

        if (isinstance(self, C)):
            self.method_need_C()

        if (isinstance(self, B)):
            print(self.attr_need_B)

        if (isinstance(self, C)):
            print(self.attr_need_C)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")
        self.attr_need_B = "I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B"
        A.__init__(self)

    def method_need_B(self):
        print("I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")
        self.attr_need_C = "I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in C"
        B.__init__(self)

    def method_need_C(self):
        print("I am 'method' and A need me, but live in C")

c = B()
```

The output now does not give you any errors:

```
B.__init__
A.__init__:  <__main__.B object at 0x000001F82AA57F70>
I am 'method' and A need me, but live in B
I am 'attribute' and A need me, but live in B
```

That's because you're testing to see if `self` is an instance of `class C` or `class B` and prevent accessing methods and properties that do not exist, in case they are not instances of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Because they do not exist inside A class.

Not only pycharm cannot find references. The python interpreter would not be able to find it as well. If you will try such instruction:

`a = A()`

you will get error.

Why your code sample works though?
You are calling inside `C.__init__` such instruction: `B.__init__(self)`, the `self` object does have the `method_need_C`, and going down, you add second method the same way in the B class. So the `self` in the A class does have those two methods.